# JUnit tests for app engine full-text search

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Is it possible to write JUnit tests for app engine's full-text search?

I couldn’t find any equivalent of LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig for search.

I tried running Junits with just local datastore config and my index is returning extra/incorrect results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use

```
new LocalSearchServiceTestConfig()
```

available in `com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing`, the same package as the Datastore test config.

Comment: It's kind of weird that Google doesn't mention about existence of this class in its own [javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/)

Comment: If this has answered your question, please remember to accept the answer. If not feel free to comment or edit your question.